# Under what file do you write twilio code in order to input instance variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, twilio

So the way that my app works is that a user enters a message, and a phone number to send that message to. The app sends the message using the Twilio gem. I'm trying to figure out how to call the variables that are stored from the user input into my twilio code.

## messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @message = Message.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.create(message_params)
    @message.send_sms(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to @message
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Contact not send message!"
    end
  end

  def update
      if @message.update(message_params)
        redirect_to @message
      else
        render :edit
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @message.destroy
    redirect_to messages_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allowset_message         the white list through.
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:number, :text)
    end

end
```

## twilio code

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

    def send_sms(text)
        account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_SID"] 
        auth_token = ENV["TWILIO_TOKEN"] 

        @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

        message = @client.account.messages.create(:body => @message.text,
         :to => @message.number,
         :from => ENV["FROM"]) 

         rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to split that code into different files.

Let's start with your controller. Your create method looks like you want to send a message via Trello and that you want to store the message in your database too. I would write the controller's create method like this:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  if @message.save_and_send         # Note the name of the method
    redirect_to @message
  else 
    flash[:alert] = "Contact not send message!"
    # render `new` again if this wasn't successful and 
    # show errors on the form (if exist).
    render :new             
  end
end
```

In a next step I introduce a `save_and_send` method in `message.rb` that validates and sends the message and returns `true` if both was successful:

```
def save_and_send
  save! if valid? && SmsGateway.send(self)
end
```

This method first validates the record. If it is valid it tries to send the message. And if the message was successfully send, it saves the record using `save!` (because at this point it should not fail).

I added the new model `SmsGateway`, because IMHO it is a good practise to encapsulate third party code into wrappers, because that makes it easier to maintain and to change the SMS provider in the future. The `SmsGateway` class is pretty simeple:

```
# in app/models/sms_gateway.rb
require 'twilio-ruby'

class sms_gateway    
  def self.send(message)
    new.send(message)
  end

  def initialize
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV["TWILIO_SID"], ENV["TWILIO_TOKEN"])
  end

  def send(message)
    client.account.messages.create(
      body: message.text,
      to: message.number,
      from: ENV["FROM"])
    )
  rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
    Rails.logger.error("SMS ERROR: #{e.message}")
    message.errors.add(:base, "Sending the message failed: #{e.message}")
    false
  end

private

  attr_reader :client
end
```

In the rescue block of the `SmsGateway` I write an error to the `message` instance if there the message was not be able to send and I return `false`. This `false` ensures in `Message#save_and_send` that the message itself is not stored in the database. And that we are able to show proper error messages back to the user.

Comment: I implemented the code as you suggested, and it's continuously raises new errors as I fix them. For example, it raises a noMethodError in reference to the private method "send" in the sms_gateway

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote my answer with the possibility to test it. You are right, the `save` method cannot be private. I updated my answer.

Comment: [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-send) is a method that you never want to define in Ruby. It's used to pass messages to objects, those messages being the method calls you want to call. I've made the mistake of defining `send` before and it just broke things. Can I recommend the method name `deliver` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was curious, the answer is that you put the method in the controller under private. You call it simply by

```
def create
    send_sms(message_params)
end
```

Also, the argument in the method should be message_params as well.

I did it!!!!!